# Freeform module won't install - just shows blank screen/white page

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

This is the first time I have run into issues with installing Freeform. I am running Expression Engine 2.7.2, I have the latest free version of Freeform (4.1.3) and when I go to Add Ons > Modules > Freeform and hit install I arrive at Package Settings which tells me to install both the Accessory and the Module.

So far so good - then I hit Submit to install both the Accessory and the Module and... white page of death.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Enable debugging in your **admin.php** or **system/index.php** file so you can see what error is killing the installation.

Comment: Thanks Derek - this led me to the solution. The debug message said something to the effect of invalid characters at the end of **system/index.php** which turned out to be a bunch of NULL symbols. I have noticed this throughout the files since mounting my FTP server - so I removed Freeform (after adding it via mounted server) and went for a straight up FTP upload and now it's working. Thanks!